# How are "related" work items for pull requests determined in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

I've recently discovered that work items linked to pull requests can be used when seeing which work items are associated with different deployments. That said, I want to make sure the related work items are accurate. I *could* link my work items manually, but in some cases there can be 50 different commits going out in a single squash merge commit. That is a lot of different commits to have to manually enter in.

I see VSTS (Azure Devops) tries to automatically add some related work items. **The problem is that I do not know how these work items are being calculated right now.** As you can see from the image below, you can have associated work items even if no code changes are detected. Can someone please shed some light on this? According to Fiddler, the API called for this in the VSTS api is:

```
// POST https://foobar.visualstudio.com/16e07dde-f652-4a64-93f1-3edb3d70d5e1/_apis/git/repositories/c9bd207c-bc6e-4e6c-aba9-8fd6aeb53946/commitsBatch 

{"$top":101,"itemVersion":{"versionOptions":0,"versionType":0,"version":"master"},"compareVersion":{"versionOptions":0,"versionType":0,"version":"users/v-username/140357_TestBranchForFeatureDeployment_ButWithLinks"}}
```

[image: A bunch of related work items even though no code changes are detected.]

Comment: May I know how's the progress going? Does your scenario satisfied the below issue I mentioned? Free to comment below if you still has any puzzle on it:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Pull Request, e.g from `dev` to `master`, it will detect the commits which differ between these 2 branches firstly. It is the `commitsbatch` api you saw from the Fiddler trace.

For `work items` listed in the pull request, it is the one which **associated** with the commit. When detecting the commits, the associated work items are detected and listed also. These are what you saw in the above screenshots you shared.

---

I think the you most concerned and confused should be why it display **100 commits** but still said **No file changes** in this pull request.

Based on my known, it seems be the known limitation of Azure devops PR. See this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51306/pull-request-diff-does-not-update-when-a-commit-fr.html) which reported to us before.

> For example take the following branches and commits:
>
> feature/task-1:
>
> ```
> commit e48b5a97d33abf733df656ebc2bf81cedccf7815
> ```
>
> feature/task-2:
>
> ```
> commit e48b5a97d33abf733df656ebc2bf81cedccf7815
>
> commit 6a6c2db2c71a584bd07632c7387b7bee3fb32eea
> ```
>
> If `feature/task-1` and `feature/task-2` are both Pull-Requested to
>   develop, after `feature/task-1` is merged, the pull request for
>   `feature/task-2` will still show changes from commits
>   `e48b5a97d33abf733df656ebc2bf81cedccf7815` and
>   `6a6c2db2c71a584bd07632c7387b7bee3fb32eea` even though
>   `e48b5a97d33abf733df656ebc2bf81cedccf7815` has already been merged into
>   develop.

With this limitation, the commits still be detected, but since the file changes has been merged by other branch previously, so it will say no file changes. Also, the work items which associated with the commits are displayed.

Just check it and confirm whether it is what you are facing. If yes, try with the work around our engineer mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/59494/view.html).

Or you could raise the new ticket on that forum, to let the corresponding product group make focus on it.

Comment: I believe the issue was being caused by only being able to squash commit into master so even though dev and master are in sync according to files, they would be out of sync according to commit history.